# Custom Filling Order of cells in Collection View

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

By Default the collection view fills its cells in the pattern as shown below:

```
1  4  7  10

2  5  8  11

3  6  9  12
```

I want to change my collection view's filling behaviour and want to fill my cells in the order as shown below:

```
1   2   3   4

5   6   7   8

9   10  11  12
```

Need to do it in a single collection view..
Any such easy approach suggested will be appreciated.

Comment: please show us your code.

Comment: You are wrong, by default `UICollectionView` fills the cell in the lower style not as a upper style.

Comment: What you want is default property of CollectionView please recheck it once.

Answer (score 0):

Set the [`collectionViewLayout`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionview/1618047-collectionviewlayout) property of your [`UICollectionView`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionview) to a [UICollectionViewFlowLayout](http://UICollectionViewFlowLayout) with a [`horizontal`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionviewscrolldirection/1617698-horizontal) [`scrollDirection`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionviewflowlayout/1617720-scrolldirection).

Alternatively, if your `UICollectionView` is defined in interface builder, its flow direction can be selected by a drop down menu in the inspector.

Comment: with a `vertical`